# MOUSE_DOWN not firing when expected - AS3, Actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, mouseevent

**MOUSE_DOWN not firing when expected** - AS3, Actionscript

I am not seeing the below code trace in MOUSE_DOWN fired, *until* I lift the mouse button back up.

This happens even on a new FLA, with only MOUSE_DOWN, MOUSE_UP and CLICK handler code -- nothing else.

Regardless of what I do, I only see MOUSE_DOWN, MOUSE_UP and CLICK traced out AFTER I lift (release) the mouse button..
See code below.

It happens if I attach the handlers to the stage;
or to a sprite.

It happens with/without buttonMode being set.

It happens with/without preventDefault() being called in CLICK..

It happens using event:MouseEvewnt or event:Event as some have suggested.

When I click, I see nothing.
When I release, I see this:
Mouse down
Mouse up
Mouse CLICK

Why don't I see "Mouse down" when clicking (before releasing)?

What the heck am I missing here?

Thank you!

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, function(event:MouseEvent)
             {
                // event.preventDefault();  
                 trace("Mouse down");   
             } );

 stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, function(event:MouseEvent)
            {
                // event.preventDefault();
                trace("Mouse up");
            } );

 stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(event:Event)
        {
            // event.preventDefault();
            trace("Mouse CLICK");

        } );
```

Comment: What is your IDE?  Adobe Animate/FlashPro?   That code should work the way you expect.

Comment: Sorry.  I am using a freshly installed, fully updated, Flash Pro CS6.  Created a new Actionscript FLA, and pasted that code in to test.

Comment: I have the latest (Animate 2015.3) and pasted it in and it worked fine.  Seems likely to be some kind of environment issue.